# In-place editing X-editable in Rails No Route Matches [POST]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using Rails 3 and [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/) for in-place editing. After adding the necessary files, when I try to update, it returns `No route matches [POST]`.

I have tried the following different lines of code:

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-original-title="Enter username">superuser</a>

<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-resource="post" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-original-title="Enter username">superuser</a>

<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-model="post" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-original-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```

I have coded my controller to accept JSON, but no data seems to be fed to the controller at all.

What did I miss? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the route defined in your routes.rb file?

Comment: Yes, I have. Normal edit/update works fine.

Comment: The message is telling you that is is receiving a POST request via HTTP for a route it doesn't know about.  Can you attach your routes file and the controller section related to it, and the section of the view with the form in it?

Comment: @muttonlamb, I took your advice and re-check again, and clearly I missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@muttonlamb is right. I should have checked properly. `post` isn't in the route, and `put` is instead.

According to [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), to edit an existing record, `put` should be used, not `post`. `post` is only for new record.

The default ajax call for x-editable is `post`, but I can change it to `put` using the following:

```
$().editable({
  ajaxOptions: {
    type: 'put'
  }
});
```

More options can be found here: http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/docs.html#editable